# CSS background DIV resizing itself while resizing the browser

Tags: html, css

Simple issue but couldn't fix it.

```html
<div class="bg">
    <div class="container2">
        <p> Test content goes here </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two `div` one is `bg` which has a background and second one is container.

```html
<style>
.bg {
    background:#0C9;
}
    
.container2 {
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;  
}
</style>
```

The problem is that on resizing the browser width, the background `div` resizes itself from the right side.

Can anyone help to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

finally fixed it , min-width was the problem , added to container div and its fixed